# How can I make a "reverse preventDefault" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, preventdefault

In [Private Logistics: Privacy-Sensitive Calendar, Todo, and Personal Information Management](http://JonathansCorner.com/private-logistics/), data that is entered can be edited with a click, and there is support for either entering a link as <a href="... or entering a URL, which will be linkified.

This works great but it presents a problem when someone clicks on a link. The desired behavior is for the link to open and not to put the snippet of text into edit mode, which is the reverse of the usual pattern implemented by `event.preventDefault()' or '...return false;}`. (Clicks outside the link on the element should put the containing element in edit mode, same as a container that doesn't happen to have a link.)

***How can I reverse the more common pattern*** using jQuery? My best guess now is to attempt introspection on the event target and see if it is an anchor. But that's just a best guess; I have seen plenty of examples of the pattern that would cancel the link loading another page but performing the added Ajax functionality of putting the container into edit mode; I'm not sure I've seen the reverse of that pattern which would follow the link and not put the container into edit mode.

I also see a way to dodge the matter by having links load in the same page, but that's the sort of solution I'd prefer to only adopt if there are intractable issues with implementation or the like.

Comment: Is it an option to just not intercept clicks on links, but only on a whitelist of editable elements that you generated? (Using e.g. a CSS class.) Then you could attach a handler that calls [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the links you create with the linkification.

Comment: Even if clicking the link does something, it'd just take you to the linked page so it wouldn't matter anyway, right?

Comment: stopPropagation prevents the event from travelling upstream; preventDefault stops the default behavior of an element; return false would do both.  The problem you're experiencing sounds like you have a click event occurring on a valid link preventing the default behavior of the anchor.  My suggestion would be to be more specific as to which anchor elements implement that click event by modifying the selector.

Comment: @sachleen The link opens a new window, so the old window is there, with the field in edit mode, when the user tabs back.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want to clean up your broad strokes, instead, don't make such broad strokes. Use an `if` statement prior to running `e.preventDefault()`.

Something like:

```
var preventedLinks = $('a.preventthislink');
$('a').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).index(preventedLinks) != -1) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, you are giving a refined view of the event.preventDefault() technique, with more sophistication in preventing the links from opening and letting the line go to edit mode. But what I want is to have the links open and not put the line in edit mode, which is the exact opposite of what you usually use preventDefault() for. Does this do the exact opposite? It looks to me like a more precise way of doing something I don't want to do.

Comment: No, this doesn't do what you're asking, I'm suggesting rather than doing it after the fact, preemptively fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could alternatively just change the class of whatever you are preventing default on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass('green');
});
```